# connman network instability

Tags: linux, networking, embedded-linux, connman

I posted to connman@lists.01.org, but it bounced back that email list could not be delivered. What is going on with connman mailing list? Is it still active?

I am running connman version 1.37, it could display the LTE wwan0 network interface when the device was started, after an hour or more, the wwan0 network mysteriously disappeared, but could still see the wwan0 and IP address available through dbus:
dict entry(
string "Address"
variant string "10.159.153.3"
)

Why couldn't connman display the network and IP when it was still available throught dbus? If I restarted connman, the wwan0 network could be back again.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The connman mailing list is here now:

```
connman@lists.linux.dev
```

It looks like it very recently moved there, as we can see that they updated the README with this info just about a month ago:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/connman/connman.git/commit/?id=a368bc405